# Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode in [background: url({{XXX}}) no-repeat center center

Tags: javascript, angular, microsoft-edge, es5-shim

I am getting this error in Edge but in chrome everything is fine 
Unable to understand what is wrong here...

```
<div class="container-fluid project_img" style="background: url({{_project.images.web}}) no-repeat center center;">
      </div>
```

Error in Microsoft Edge:

```
Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode in [background: url({{_project.images.web}}) no-repeat center center; in ProjectDetailComponent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead

```
<div class="container-fluid project_img" [style.background]="'url(' + _project.images.web + ') no-repeat center center;'">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude it helped

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me

```
<div class="container-fluid project_img" attr.style.background="url({{_project.images.web}}) no-repeat center center;">
```

Comment: Both styles should work. You just can't use `[xxx]="..." and `{{...}}` together.